# Underwater Convolution IRs?

Tags: ir, convolution, underwater

Hi All,

Does anyone know where I can get a free or cheap decent underwater or 'river' IR? In the past I have loaded the sound of a stone being dropped in water as my IR but I want to see if there's a better option.

Thanks!
Jeremy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pitched down water bubbles

Comment: And Tim's work here is done ;)

Comment: @tim, brilliant idea. I am trying that tomorrow. 

Answer (score 1):

Not an IR, but a great library to help create the mood

http://www.tonsturm.com/files/d7b786b29f6e37689f7c0f8ea7a705b5-21.html

Answer (score 1):

I used a glass hit as an impulse for fish in a fish tank POV.